# Help with Test Class for trigger and apex class

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I am new to Apex test classes and I have a trigger and class that is working for my org but I have no idea where to start to get them to have coverage. Anyone able to help me on this?

```
public Class checkRecursive{
private static boolean run = true;
public static boolean runOnce(){
if(run){
 run=false;
 return true;
}else{
    return run;
}
}
}
```

trigger:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update)
{

if(checkRecursive.runOnce())
{
list<Account> account_Updatelist= new list<Account>();
for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
  {
     if(acc.Total_Opportunities_Won__c>=1 && acc.Active_Opportunities__c == 0 && Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).Account_Clearing_Date__c!=null && acc.Account_Clearing_Date__c == Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).Account_Clearing_Date__c + 1)
        acc.Customer_Type__c = 'Former Client';


      else if(acc.Total_Opportunities_Won__c>=1 && acc.Active_Opportunities__c >= 1)
         acc.Customer_Type__c = 'Current Client';

      else if(acc.Total_Opportunities_Won__c==0 && acc.Active_Opportunities__c==0)
         acc.Customer_Type__c = 'Prospect';

      if(acc.Active_Opportunities__c==0)
         acc.Account_Clearing_Date__c = system.today();

      else if(acc.Active_Opportunities__c>=1)
        acc.Account_Clearing_Date__c = null;

      //  account_Updatelist.add(acc);

  }

//  if(account_Updatelist!=null && account_Updatelist.size()>0)
    //  update account_Updatelist;

  }

  }
```

Comment: did you write test class?

Comment: Rather than close this for being off topic (We are not a code writing service) I am marking as a duplicate of a wiki around how to write a test class